# How to get list of states in a country through Google map API?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder, google-geocoding-api

Is it  at all possible. I had spent 5 hours researching and did not find a solution.

Does anyone knows anything?

Answer (score 4):

That is not part of the Google Maps API v3.  You can use the [Natural Earth Data set](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/) in [Fusion Tables](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/) to get that information.  [Here](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_FusionTables_query_sidebarF_local.html?country=Canada) is an example displaying the provinces of Canada on a Google Map using [FusionTablesLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#FusionTablesLayer).

Comment: This looks complicated. May be there is simple public API by some 3rd party?

Answer (score 2):

The [**Geonames**](http://www.geonames.org/) geographical database is available for download free of charge under a creative commons attribution license has various data sets that may help. The one which suits your requirements is [admin2Codes.txt](http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/admin2Codes.txt)

Answer (score 1):

Pls check out the ISO-3166-2. It is an ISO standard based on country. You need not rely on Google Maps or any other webservice. It is available as a pure JSON file.

Comment: can I have a link to get that please?